# Writing specification for custom sorting/ordering

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a requirement where I want to sort my table based on 2 columns.
Table: (ID,date_of_death date_of_birth)
I wanted to order the data on both date_of_death and date_of_birth dates in ascending order. Also date_of_death could be null for some of the data.
If I wanted to form a sql query, i could write it like this

```
Select ID,date_of_birth,date_of_death from SOMETABLE ORDER BY CASE
WHEN date_of_birth IS NULL THEN date_of_death
ELSE date_of_death
END;
```

Since I am using Spring specification all over, I didn't want to inject this query directly, so was wondering , if there is any way to get this done using specifications. Any pointers will also help here.
Thanks

Comment: Do you know the class `CriteriaBuilder`? You can also take a look at `coalesce`, it will avoid you using `CASE` statements.

Comment: date_of_birth < date_of_death might be `NULL` too, expect date_of_death to be nullable

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle  Only if you are not a time lord ;)

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Sadly, `date_of_birth` and `date_of_death` could be the same.